# Permission error when using Ajax on a protocol other than http

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, cross-domain

We are using a custom protocol handler to connect to an embedded device across firewalls, NAT etc. The solution is called [Nabto](http://nabto.com).
This works great - a plug-in on the user's computer handles requests to all nabto:// URIs and serves HTML pages with information about the current connections etc.

Now, we would like to access Nabto functionality from a regular web page. This is difficult with browsers enforcing the Same-Origin policy (e.g. our http page cannot communicate with the nabto page).
So far, I am trying to solve this using [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net) by having a "proxy page" served by the nabto plug-in. This page is then allowed to launch nabto:// requests and can communicate the results back to the http page using easyXDM.

However, same-origin requests fail in Internet Explorer - even when both pages reside in the nabto://self domain. I get this error: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XALFe.png)

Is this an error in Internet Explorer? Any idea how to solve it?

Thanks a lot,
Martin

Comment: Looks strange. *Is* `nabto://self` in your trusted sites list? (If it's even possible to add it, it could be that it accepts only `http://` and `https://`)

Comment: It is in my trusted pages, yes. 
But it seems to not make any difference - if I remove it, ajax calls will still fail with "Permission Denied". Likewise, I cannot access the document contents of an embedded iframe in the same nabto:// domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had huge issues that sound similar to yours when developing the plugin. I must admit that we gave up getting clean Ajax support working through Nabto after spending a lot of time on it. In fact, the final thing that happened was opening a support case with Microsoft about it, the case bounced around and we never heard anything back.

There might be a chance though for a hack: In the meantime we realized that IE allows you to populate images through nabto:// urls on an http / https page. Maybe you can populate an image object through your query and extract the result from there?

On a side note: You are welcome to post in the support forums (forum.nabto.com) about such things. On the other hand, you help spread the word about the product in this way ;-)

Ulrik

Comment: Hey Ulrik! Thanks for the answer - in fact, I am pretty certain that my employer is working directly with you guys (does Comfort ring a bell? :-)
I ended up abandoning Ajax - but it should be noted that the inter-frame, cross-domain communication can be obtained using [this plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/). This is what we will be using for the time being - I highly recommend it.
Martin

Comment: Ah, indeed! You are doing a recreational nabto project? Cool :-)